# Form submit workflow fired without actual submit

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow for a form submit. Recently this got fired and sent out 100s of email all of them mentioning that the form has been modified by one particular user. And when checked with this user, he haven't accessed this for several months. The modified coloumn is also showing his name. 
Can anyone help me on this.
It would be really helpful as I'm a beginner with sharepoint.